Why in loss function of DQN does the expectation depend on current state $s$?
Please see slide 39 in https://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2017/cs231n_2017_lecture14.pdf
Why in loss function of DQN  does the expectation  depend on current state $s$?

In DQN the loss function is designed to minimize the difference between the prediction network's $Q(s,a;\theta)$ and the target network's $Q^*(s,a)$ computed using the Bellman optimality equation as a conditional expectation defined on slide 39 of your reference. Since the target $Q^*(s,a)$ depends on the current state $s$, the expectation is taken over the distribution of transitions $(s,a,r,s′)$ encountered during training from the replay buffer, thus the loss function inherently depends on the current state $s$. The dependence on the current state reflects the idea that we want to learn a policy that is effective across the entire state space, not just for a specific state.
